# Adding headers to jsonArrayRequest using Volley Android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I want to send jsonArray and also some header with it to the server using Volley. I have used the following way:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest( Request.Method.POST, URL, jsonParams, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "JSON response: " +response );
     }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         error.printStackTrace();
         Log.d( LOG_TAG, "Error data: " + error.toString());
         String errorResponse = Arrays.toString( error.getStackTrace() );
         Log.d( LOG_TAG, "Volley response: " + errorResponse);
         Log.d( LOG_TAG, "Network response: " +error.networkResponse.statusCode );
         Log.d( LOG_TAG, "Volley error: " + error.getMessage()+"\n"+ Log.getStackTraceString( error ));
     }
})
 {
     @Override
     public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
         HashMap < String, String > headers = new HashMap<>();
         headers.put( USER_TOKEN, mUserToken );
         return headers;
 }};
```

Here, I am getting status code as 405, on hitting the URL.
I want to send a user token as a header along with the jsonArray but unsuccessful.
jsonParams is json Array that can contain one or multiple json objects.
Can anybody guide me for what is the correct way of adding headers or any other solution?

Comment: Do you need to send this as Header ? I mean could you can just send your token as a param ?

Comment: No, it is to be sent as an header.

Comment: your request parameter is json array or you want response as a json array?
If response is only json not a json array then change  JsonArrayRequest to JsonRequest and try.

Answer (score 0):

When you get 405 status code from server means that you are sending wrong method to server. In short POST method need to be GET method vice versa.

Comment: I tried with GET but I am getting the same response.